# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: sockets, mariadb

I just formatted my drive and installed MariaDB on Linux Mint 17.

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.1-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

I typed: mysql -u root -p
gave it my passowrd and got this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

I did a search and found mysqld.sock was missing. I've read a lot of posts on this but nothing that's fixed this for me. How do I get mysqld.sock? Do I have to install some MySQL files to get it? If so, will this affect MariaDB?

Comment: 1) Have you verified that you have a `mysqld` process running at all (it is still called `mysqld` with MariaDB)?
2) If it is indeed running: check what ports/sockets it is listening on with `sudo netstat -lnp | grep mysqld`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
    sudo service mysql stop
    sudo service mysql restart
```